# Get watched issues in Redmine via REST API

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, redmine

We're looking to create a tool to help with time management in Redmine.  The issue we are currently having is that we want to get a list of issues that are watched by a particular user but can't find an API for it.  Does anyone know if this is possible or are we just going to have to try and modify Redmine directly?

SOLUTION: Similar to the solution provided below by dmf85, I found a solution to this problem that worked for me.  The [Issues API](http://www.redmine.org/projects/redmine/wiki/Rest_Issues) takes a query_id as one of its parameters.  What I ended up doing was filtering my issues by Watcher (like dmf85 said) then saving the query.  I then used the query_id from that saved custom query in my API call.

Comment: Any upvote yet? It is quite a good question. We are currently having the same need

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Under your issues tab in the interface, click:

- add filter
- watcher
- select a watcher in the box

Then, click the atom, csv, or pdf link at the bottom for a link that you can write a program to consume at your discretion.

Does this help?

Comment: Yeah, that's about what I was looking for just in JSON.  I was looking through the API docs not thinking that I could just consume one of those links.  I found a similar solution myself that I am adding above but I'm marking this as the solution for simplicity.  Thanks!

Comment: Very good! Glad you found the JSON way, because XML is not my preferred markup for resources.

Answer (score 2):

At least in Redmine 3.1, there’s an undocumented parameter for the [Issues API](http://www.redmine.org/projects/redmine/wiki/Rest_Issues) that allows you to specify a watcher directly: `watcher_id`. It works just like `assigned_to_id`, you can pass either a user ID (i.e. `watcher_id=23`) or the special string `me` (i.e. `watcher_id=me`).

An example of URL could be like the following: `https://example.com/redmine/issues.json?watcher_id=me&key=redmine_api_key`

Comment: Absolutly right. This should be the accepted answer. Answers properly to OP's question.